# File stored in Google Cloud Storage not publicly available

Tags: google-app-engine

To programmatically store a file in Google Cloud Storage I followed the instructions at:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/building-app/cloud-storage

The file does get uploaded but when I attempt to view the file at:

> https://storage.googleapis.com/myapp.appspot.com/myimage.jpg

access is denied.

In the GAE admin console it is obvious that the checkmark to make the file public is not checked yet the code to store it uses:

`builder.acl("public-read");`

The docs however state:

> The previous sections in this guide show how to store publicly
>   viewable images in Cloud Storage

So I'm at a loss as to how to programmatically make the file public.

Answer (score 3):

In your cloud storage console (https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser?project=YOURPROJECT), check this setting for the bucket:

[image]

Programmatically, something like this works in python:

```
import cloudstorage as gcs

with gcs.open(filename, 'w', options={'x-goog-acl': 'public-read'}) as f:
    f.write(image_bytes)
    f.close()
```

Comment: I just figured that out. That will work but it also makes everything in the entire bucket public. I was kind of looking for a programmatic way of making only certain files (actually entire folders) public. There seems to be two separate client libs that work with GCS but only one of them lets you programmatically set the ACL. The code sample I gave in my post seems to be outdated from Google even though it was taken from their docs.

Comment: BTW, that UI you posted is out of date. The menu doesn't look like that.

Comment: It's a screenshot from today!  Not out of date.  Perhaps browser GUI diffs.  See update for programmatical setting.  If you found the solution, you should post it here.

Comment: Oops. You're right. I was looking at the top of the screen where and not further down.